# I am not able to get response from web service using Angular javascript

Tags: angularjs

var msg = document.getElementById('inputXML').innerHTML;How to pass input xml as a parameter to web service and displaying response from web service using angular javascript in html.
Here is my code, please help, i m not able to get reponse from web service.

```
<div ng-app="customerApp" ng-controller="customersController">

    <ul>
        HI<br><br><li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('customerApp');

app.factory(
        "setAsXMLPost",
        function() {
            //prepare the request data for the form post.
            function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {
                var headers = getHeaders();
              headers[ "Content-type" ] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
                // using parsexml for xml
                return(jQuery.parseXML(data));
            }
            return(transformRequest);
        }
);




    function customersController($scope, $http, setAsXMLPost) {
        var msg = document.getElementById('inputXML').innerHTML;
        $http.post("url.asmx", msg, {transformRequest: setAsXMLPost}).success(function(response) {
                    $scope.names = response;
                });
    }
</script>
<div id="inputXML">
    <ACORD> <SignonRq> <UserId>CUser</UserId> <Password>XuViDgegi/KtGyJuXfuMrw==</Password>
    <SignonPswd> <CustId> < </ACORD>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `xml` but you are not posting it, use `innerHTML` to get actual xml from `<div id="inputXML">`.

```
inputXML : msg.innerHTML // use innerHTML to get the actual xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not retriving the content of the div. You are simply extracting `#inputXML` node from the DOM tree. You can try is

```
var msg = document.getElementById('inputXML').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

in var msg you are getting a javascript object though you need complete html to process so it should be

```
var = document.getElementById('inputXML').innerHTML;
```

Also default tranformRequest of $http in angular js is json you will have to change it to text/xml i wrote an article on how you could change it [tranformRequest example angularjs](http://blog.yiiframe.com/angularjs/angularjs-simple-form-post-example-with-php/)

complete example, filename is test.php placed at root

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ){
    $xmlData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . $xmlData;
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<body >
<title>Simple xml post in angularjs Web Application</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Simple xml post in angularjs Web Application">
    <div ng-app="customerApp" ng-controller="customersController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in users">{{x}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="inputXML">
    <ACORD>
        <SignonRq><UserId>CUser1</UserId><Password>XuViDgegi/KtGyJuXfuMrw==</Password></SignonRq>
        <SignonRq><UserId>CUser2</UserId><Password>XuViDgegi/KtGyJuXfuMrw==1</Password></SignonRq>
    </ACORD>
</div>    <!-- Libraries -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('customerApp', []);

app.factory(
        "setAsXMLPost",
        function() {
            //prepare the request data for the form post.
            function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {
                var headers = getHeaders();
                headers[ "Content-type" ] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
                // using parsexml for xml
                return(jQuery.parseXML(data));
            }
            return(transformRequest);
        }
);

app.factory(
        "getAsXML",
        function() {
            //prepare the request data for the form post.
            function transformResponse(data, getHeaders) {
                var headers = getHeaders();
                headers[ "Content-type" ] = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
                // using parsexml for xml
                return(jQuery.parseXML(data));
            }
            return(transformResponse);
        }
);
function customersController($scope, $http, setAsXMLPost, getAsXML) {
    var msg = document.getElementById('inputXML').innerHTML;
    $scope.users = [];
    $http.post("test.php", msg, {transformRequest: setAsXMLPost, transformResponse: getAsXML}).success(function(returnedXMLResponse) {
        //here you will get xml object in reponse in returnedXMLResponse
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please post you http://nordevd208wa1x.csc-fsg.com/TPOServiceEnh7/TPOService/TPOService.asmx code

Also please correct your js from my edited answer

Comment: I was checking on my machine and your api resulting in "NetworkError: 504 Gateway Timeout - http://nordevd208wa1x.csc-fsg.com/TPOServiceEnh7/TPOService/TPOService.asmx". please check your api is working fine ?

Comment: Sir it is just displaying the input XML..that i have written in <div>

Comment: Also, On debugging your edited script it showing an error that- Uncaught Reference error- app   not defined

Comment: edited your question for the error. now please check and let me know if you still face any error

Comment: Sir i want xml reponse from my asmx web service as i pass my input xml...but your code is just returning me my same input xml nodes.

Comment: angular.js:36 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?p0=customerApp
angular.js:36 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=customerApp&p1=Err…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)

Comment: Aman can you please share you webservice code, what we are doing in the above code is, posting a xml request to your webservice and expected response should be JSON beacuse we have not changed tranformResponse anywhere and default content type for transformResponse is json.

Comment: for the error change var app = angular.module('customerApp'); to var app = angular.module('customerApp', []);

Comment: can you make a plunker of your code http://plnkr.co/ so that i can debug it myself

Comment: Sir could u pls give me a dummy code for hitting webservice with xml as input request and displaying xml response from web service....our web service accepts only xml input not jason...and web service is working fine.

Comment: OK Aman I will write and share an article on it explaining xml request and response with angular,  with some example code.

Comment: meanwhile can you send me your detailed requirement so that i can write the program accordingly

Comment: I just want to send an request xml using angular js in html to asmx web service and in response i want to display response xml that my web service will send after receiving request xml

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at transformRequest (http://localhost:8080/Angular_dummy/New.html:30:24)
    at xc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:68:500)
    at f (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:71:242)
    at F (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.m

Comment: edited my answer for a complete demo example using PHP as server side language. I dont have good idea with asmx services so i used php.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. But my web service accepts only xml reqest...so could u pls help me in creating a middleware which can convert jason to xml for request and vice-a-versa for reponse?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your controller is executing correctly, I think the standard controller declaration would be something like this:

```
.controller('customersController', ['$scope', '$http', 'setAsXMLPost',function($scope, $http, setAsXMLPost){
    var msg = document.getElementById('inputXML').innerHTML;
    $http.post("http://nordevd208wa1x.csc-fsg.com/TPOServiceEnh7/TPOService/TPOService.asmx", msg, {transformRequest: setAsXMLPost}).success(function(response) {
        $scope.names = response;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: New.html:39 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
angular.js:36 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=customerApp&p1=Err…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)